# HTML, CSS, dynamic float:right and "unfloat"

Tags: html, css

I have a row of button-like text links, most of which I want aligned to left, except one.

My CSS sheet is way to long to post but essentially:

```
.button-bar-float-right{
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .button-bar-float-right{
    float: none;
  }
  ...
}
```

This, examined in Chrome Developer Tools, starts a chosen button nicely in float mode far to the right of others but still in a line (when the window is wide), then (when narrowed) it becomes a display:block like other buttons, but the button DOES NOT return it to its correct position when wide again (it aligns to the right, but does not return to the same line).

What's wrong?

(Also some naive questions follow: 
- Does the order of styles matter within a device query block (i.e. are there invalid states that prevent form reassigning a property?) 
- Do I have to set tags with opposite properties to have it revert dynamically? )

Comment: or is float just a non-dynamically-reversible property?

Comment: It works for me: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cj501mu1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we don't have enough information to reproduce your issue (see Oriol's link), I'll answer the questions at the end of your post:

> Does the order of styles matter within a device query block (i.e. are there invalid states that prevent form reassigning a property?

The order of styles only matters as far as CSS rule precedence goes - rules of the highest weight take precedence no matter what order they are in. When there is a tie for the highest precedence, the last one wins.

> Do I have to set tags with opposite properties to have it revert dynamically?

No, only CSS rules that are applicable at any given time are applied. The moment they cease to be applicable, their effect goes away.

Comment: I appreciate that, but my inherited CSS is about 1900 lines long. And I was looking for a hint which other styles might be interfering with it (i.e. common errors).

Trimming it by trial an error, to make an MCVE of the issue, would pretty much mean having solved the problem by trial and error. Which I'm working on, but you know...

Comment: @DailyFrankPeter In that case, I suggest you use your browser debugging tools to inspect that element and the ones around it. It should tell you exactly which rules are in play and where they are.